# adjust wordpress menu so items are vertically centered

Tags: css, responsive-design, menu, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to customize a Wordpress menu.  It's almost where I need it but I'm having one major problem.  How do I vertically center the menu items (both the words and the image so they are perfectly centered within the light blue background.

Be sure to view the full page.  This needs to be responsive so as the window resizes the menu items stay vertically centered.

```css
/*! CSS Used from: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=5.2.3 ; media=all */
@media all{
div,a,img,ul,li,nav{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;}
ul{list-style:none;}
a:focus{outline:thin dotted;}
nav{display:block;}
img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
button{border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:3px;font-family:inherit;padding:6px;padding:0.428571429rem;}
button{line-height:normal;}
.menu-toggle{padding:6px 10px;padding:0.428571429rem 0.714285714rem;font-size:11px;font-size:0.785714286rem;line-height:1.428571429;font-weight:normal;color:#7c7c7c;background-color:#e6e6e6;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);border:1px solid #d2d2d2;border-radius:3px;box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1);}
.menu-toggle,button{cursor:pointer;}
.menu-toggle:hover,.menu-toggle:focus,button:hover{color:#5e5e5e;background-color:#ebebeb;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);}
.menu-toggle:active,button:active{color:#757575;background-color:#e1e1e1;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);box-shadow:inset 0 0 8px 2px #c6c6c6, 0 1px 0 0 #f4f4f4;border-color:transparent;}
a{outline:none;color:#21759b;}
a:hover{color:#0f3647;}
.assistive-text{position:absolute!important;clip:rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);overflow:hidden;height:1px;width:1px;}
.main-navigation .assistive-text:focus{background:#fff;border:2px solid #333;border-radius:3px;clip:auto!important;color:#000;display:block;font-size:12px;height:auto;padding:12px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;width:auto;z-index:100000;}
.main-navigation{margin-top:24px;margin-top:1.714285714rem;text-align:center;}
.main-navigation li{margin-top:24px;margin-top:1.714285714rem;font-size:12px;font-size:0.857142857rem;line-height:1.42857143;}
.main-navigation a{color:#5e5e5e;}
.main-navigation a:hover,.main-navigation a:focus{color:#21759b;}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu{display:none;}
.menu-toggle{display:inline-block;}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu{border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;border-top:1px solid #ededed;display:inline-block!important;text-align:left;width:100%;}
.main-navigation ul{margin:0;text-indent:0;}
.main-navigation li a,.main-navigation li{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}
.main-navigation li a{border-bottom:0;color:#6a6a6a;line-height:3.692307692;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap;}
.main-navigation li a:hover,.main-navigation li a:focus{color:#000;}
.main-navigation li{margin:0 40px 0 0;margin:0 2.857142857rem 0 0;position:relative;}
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,.main-navigation .current_page_item > a{color:#636363;font-weight:bold;}
.menu-toggle{display:none;}
}
@media print{
a{text-decoration:none;}
.main-navigation{display:none;}
}
}
/*! CSS Used from: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/?display_custom_css=css&ver=5.2.3 ; media=all */
@media all{
.fa{padding:1vw;padding-right:1.75vw;font-size:1.25vw!important;width:2.5vw;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;margin:.25vw .1vw;}
.fa:hover{opacity:0.7;}
@media screen and (min-width: 60px){
.menu-toggle{display:none;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60px){
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu{border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;border-top:1px solid #ededed;display:inline-block!important;text-align:right;width:100%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60px){
.main-navigation li{margin:0 2vw 0 0;position:relative;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60px){
.main-navigation li a,.main-navigation li{display:inline-block;text-decoration:none;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60px){
.main-navigation li a{border-bottom:0;color:#6a6a6a;line-height:3.692307692;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap;}
}
.menu-item-type-custom{float:left;height:0;}
.menu-item{font-size:1.5vw!important;}
.main-navigation{margin:0!important;}
#menu-1{background-color:#b3d7f7;}
#menu-1 a{height:0;}
}
/*! CSS Used from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css */
.fa{display:inline-block;font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;font-size:inherit;text-rendering:auto;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;}
/*! CSS Used fontfaces */
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');src:url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
   <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>
   <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
   <div class="menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-1" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-35"><a href="https://google.com"><img class="fa facebook" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png" scale="0"></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-25"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/home/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-work/">Our Work</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/resources/">Resources</a></li>
</ul></div>  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `margin` for `icon` class `.fa` and need to update `line-height` for the `li` to make it center check snippet.

```
.main-navigation li {
    line-height: 29px;
  }
```

```css
/*! CSS Used from: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=5.2.3 ; media=all */

@media all {
  div,
  a,
  img,
  ul,
  li,
  nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
  }
  nav {
    display: block;
  }
  img {
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  button {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 6px;
    padding: 0.428571429rem;
  }
  button {
    line-height: normal;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    padding: 0.428571429rem 0.714285714rem;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-size: 0.785714286rem;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f4f4, #e6e6e6);
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1);
  }
  .menu-toggle,
  button {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu-toggle:hover,
  .menu-toggle:focus,
  button:hover {
    color: #5e5e5e;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9, #ebebeb);
  }
  .menu-toggle:active,
  button:active {
    color: #757575;
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ebebeb, #e1e1e1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 2px #c6c6c6, 0 1px 0 0 #f4f4f4;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  a {
    outline: none;
    color: #21759b;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: #0f3647;
  }
  .assistive-text {
    position: absolute!important;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .main-navigation .assistive-text:focus {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    clip: auto!important;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
  }
  .main-navigation {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .main-navigation li {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.857142857rem;
    line-height: 29px;
  }
  .main-navigation a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
  }
  .main-navigation a:hover,
  .main-navigation a:focus {
    color: #21759b;
  }
  .main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
      border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
      display: inline-block!important;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
      margin: 0;
      text-indent: 0;
    }
    .main-navigation li a,
    .main-navigation li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .main-navigation li a {
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: #6a6a6a;
      line-height: 3.692307692;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .main-navigation li a:hover,
    .main-navigation li a:focus {
      color: #000;
    }
    .main-navigation li {
      margin: 0 40px 0 0;
      margin: 0 2.857142857rem 0 0;
      position: relative;
    }
    .main-navigation .current-menu-item>a,
    .main-navigation .current_page_item>a {
      color: #636363;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .menu-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media print {
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .main-navigation {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}


/*! CSS Used from: https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/?display_custom_css=css&ver=5.2.3 ; media=all */

@media all {
  .fa {
    padding: 1vw;
    padding-right: 1.75vw;
    font-size: 1.25vw!important;
    width: 2.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 60px) {
    .menu-toggle {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 60px) {
    .main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
      border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
      display: inline-block!important;
      text-align: right;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 60px) {
    .main-navigation li {
      margin: 0 2vw 0 0;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 60px) {
    .main-navigation li a,
    .main-navigation li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 60px) {
    .main-navigation li a {
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: #6a6a6a;
      line-height: 3.692307692;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  }
  .menu-item-type-custom {
    float: left;
    height: 0;
  }
  .menu-item {
    font-size: 1.5vw!important;
  }
  .main-navigation {
    margin: 0!important;
  }
  #menu-1 {
    background-color: #b3d7f7;
  }
  #menu-1 a {
    height: 0;
  }
}


/*! CSS Used from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css */

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}


/*! CSS Used fontfaces */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>
  <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
  <div class="menu-1-container">
    <ul id="menu-1" class="nav-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-35">
        <a href="https://google.com"><img class="fa facebook" src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png" scale="0"></a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-25"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/home/" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-story/">Our Story</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/our-work/">Our Work</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/resources/">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this is on the right track but still not really working.  The line-height needs to be expressed without px so it shrinks as the window width is decreased and the items don't really stay centered